# Adding Average Lines for each plt.plot in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, charts, data-visualization

I'm looking for help in adding an horizontal line in my plot for each plt.plot in my line plot at the average of that particular plt.plot. Each plt.plot = a season of Seinfeld and. y axis = IMDB rating and x axis = episode number of Seinfeld.

So to clarify I'm looking draw several different horizontal lines given averages of different y-values.

The output is the attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opI7d.png)
And here is my code so far:

```
# sets size for figure.
plt.figure(dpi=300)

# so you don't get 'ax' is not defined when running
ax = plt.gca()

# Put each season's IMDB rating into a variable for easy referencing
S1imdb = season_1['imdbRating'] 
S2imdb = season_2['imdbRating']
S3imdb = season_3['imdbRating']
S4imdb = season_4['imdbRating']
S5imdb = season_5['imdbRating']
S6imdb = season_6['imdbRating']
S7imdb = season_7['imdbRating']
S8imdb = season_8['imdbRating']
S9imdb = season_9['imdbRating']


# plot each season's IMDB rating separately 
plt.plot(S1imdb, label='Season 1')
plt.plot(S2imdb, label='Season 2')
plt.plot(S3imdb, label='Season 3')
plt.plot(S4imdb, label='Season 4')
plt.plot(S5imdb, label='Season 5')
plt.plot(S6imdb, label='Season 6')
plt.plot(S7imdb, label='Season 7')
plt.plot(S8imdb, label='Season 8')
plt.plot(S9imdb, label='Season 9')


# title the X and Y axes
# x axis is the episode number
# y axis is the rating from IMDB x/10

plt.xlabel('Episode Number')
plt.ylabel('IMDB Rating')

# legend
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 5})

# print out the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I just used ax.hlines and manually edited the length of the average line on the y axis based on the average of the seasons and the length on the x axis based on each seasons' index ax.hlines(7.700000, 0, 6, linewidth=1, color='k')